# How to construct an array recursively based on each parent id

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, recursion

I have a nested list of categories which DB looks something like this:

```
id      parent_id       title
83      81              test3
86      83              test1
87      83              test2
94      87              subtest2.1
95      87              subtest2.2
...etc...
```

I need to add all child element ids into the `$checked_elements` array of each parent id.

So if some specific id is selected, it's automatically added into the array of `$checked_elements`. Here how it looks like:

[image]

I'am stuck with the recursive function, on how to add recursively child items of each parent item id ? My function won't go deeper then the 2nd level, can anyone tell me how to work it out so it will check for all child items ?

```
private function delete( ){

    // Collect all checked elements into the array
    $checked_elements = $this->input->post('checked');

    // Recursive function to check for child elementts
    foreach( $checked_elements as $key => $value ){

        // Get records where parent_id is equal to $value (checked item's id)
        $childs = $this->categories_model->get_by(array('parent_id' => $value));

        // Add found record's id into the array 
        foreach( $childs as $child ){

            $checked_elements[] => $child->id;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a Multi-Dimentional from another Multi Dimensional Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685674/creating-a-multi-dimentional-from-another-multi-dimensional-array) … same issue other formulation…

Comment: @bwoebi thanks for notice, but I thing you didn't understand what I want. I want all found elements to be added into the 1 level array following as: `$key => $id`. Duplicated article is slightly different from what I want, maybe there is the same logic but that's what I'am trying to understand, would be very kind from you do get some more information about my question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try passing the accumulator array around by reference:

```
function collect($ids, &$items) {
    foreach($ids as $id){
        $items[] = $id;
        $childs = $this->categories_model->get_by(array('parent_id' => $id));
        collect(array_column($childs, 'id'), $items);
    }
    return $items;
}

function delete( ){
    $items = array();
    collect($this->input->post('checked'), $items);
    //... delete $items
}
```

In php 5.5+ you can also use generators in a way similar to this:

```
function collect($ids) {
    foreach($ids as $id) {
        yield $id;
        $childs = $this->categories_model->get_by(array('parent_id' => $id));
        foreach(collect(array_column($childs, 'id')) as $id)
            yield $id;
}


function delete( ){
    $ids = collect($this->input->post('checked'));
```

I assume your tree is rather small, otherwise I'd suggest a more efficient approach, like nested sets.

If your php version doesn't support `array_column`, you can use [this shim](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php).

Comment: Thank you Georg, but could you pls modify your answer to make it work on lower PHP version then 5.5 pls ? My server is php 5.4, and do not support `array_column()`,

Comment: @aspirinemaga: you can use a shim - I updated the post with the link.